# how to put a video on a div and that works on device android

Tags: ionic3

friends of this great community, does anyone know if it is possible to put a video on a div using ionic 3? how? I need that this works on android.
I have tried many things but without result.

this works in chrome, but tested on a device 4.4 ANDROID does not work

```
<video controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
   <source src="./assets/home-vid/intro2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, provide more info on efforts you made and share some more code.

Comment: Hi, can you use [ionic-native VideoPlayer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/) with `video` tag in html.

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar I update the question with more details

Comment: @Omsl  I update the question with more details, but how can I use  ionic-native VideoPlayer  on video tag?

Comment: You need to install `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` for android lower than 4.5

Comment: I installed this plugin, but this not works for me, tested on virtual device of android studio. What versión should I install? I am using tablet galaxy note 10.1 4.4 https://i.imgur.com/MaftPUR.jpg